# Backup database and restore it in Java program

Tags: java, derby

I have this piece of code

```
public void backUpDatabase(Connection conn)throws SQLException
{
    // Get today's date as a string:
    java.text.SimpleDateFormat todaysDate = 
       new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    String backupdirectory = "c:/mybacksup/" +
       todaysDate.format((java.util.Calendar.getInstance()).getTime());

    try (CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall("CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_BACKUP_DATABASE(?)")) { 
        cs.setString(1, backupdirectory);
        cs.execute();
        cs.close();
    }

    System.out.println("backed up database to "+backupdirectory);
}
```

Function works successfully and when I restore it by this code give me message The database has been successfully restored, but data didn't restore

```
public  Connection restoreDatabaseRoutine()
    throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {

    String backupPath = "C:\\mybacksup\\2015-05-02\\OOS_db";
    String restoreUrl = "jdbc:derby:OOS_db;restoreFrom=" + backupPath;
    String driver = "org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver";
    Class.forName(driver); // throws ClassNotFoundException
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(restoreUrl);
    System.out.println("The database has been successfully restored");
    return conn;
}
```

Comment: How do you know it didn't restore the backup? Perhaps it did restore the backup, but the data you were looking for wasn't in that backup?

Comment: Because, after backing backup of the database I deleted certain fields and when I restored the database, I do not get the copy of the database from the time of the backup.